# How to store custom objects (and List of them) as columns into a SQLite database?

Tags: android, sql, xml, database, sqlite

I retrieve some objects from an endpoint using Retrofit. The response is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<crm method="getclients”>
    <result>0</result>
    <clients>
          <client>
               <idcliente>101</idcliente>
               <name> SpaceX </name>
               <addresses> 
                      <address>
                           <idaddress>1</idaddress>
                           <name> 1 Rocket Rd Hawthorne </name>
                           <persons>
                                 <person>
                                      <idperson>1</idperson>
                                      <name>Elon Musk</name>
                                 </person>
                                 <person>
                                      <idperson>2</idperson>
                                      <name>Gwynne Shotwell</name>
                                 </person>
                           </persons>
                           <places> 
                                <place>
                                     <idplace>1</idplace>
                                     <name>Engineering Room</name>
                                </place>
                                <place>
                                     <idplace>2</idplace>
                                     <name>Main Hall</name>
                                </place>
                                <place>...</place>  
                                <place>...</place>      
                           </places>
                      </address>
                      <address>
                         ....
                      </address>
               </addresses>
          </client>
          <client>...</client>
          <client>...</client>
          <client>...</client>
    </clients>
</crm>
```

So, I need to store all the `Client`s with their respective `Address`es, each of whom with their respective `Person`s and `Place`s. 
My goal therefore is to create a Database that can store the clients and by retrieving a `Client` I could access its `Address`es and subsequently its addresses' `Person`s and `Places`.

By using Retrofit with SimpleXml as converter, I get these as objects from POJO's. **So, how could I then store these `Client` objects into a database?** What I need specifically is to discover how to store a list of `Address` into a column of `Client` and how to get for each of these `Address` in this list, their respective list of `Person` and `Place`.

In trying to accomplish, I read that I would need to store these objects as either XML or JSON. So, using `gson`, for instance, would transform an `Address` into a json address object but would I need to create another table for `Address` and others for `Person` and `Place`?

I am a beginner in databases and therefore I am pretty lost. It would be overwhelming if someone could answer this in the form of a tutorial, complete explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of 2 possible ways to do this:

1. Either store your POJOs as tables with columns. Maybe Room would be a good option for this. I think this is more work to implement.
2. Have an XML which contains the structure of your data and store your XML in the database (as String for example). Then you could read and parse the XML when retrieving it  from the database. You could use SimpleXML for this for example.